# /system/bin/cat /dev/graphics/fb0 > Is not working all android rooted mobiles why ?

Tags: android, root

i am trying to work screenshot application using the following command for Rooted phones only . 
**/system/bin/cat /dev/graphics/fb0 >**  But its not working on all the android mobiles . Why ? 
Please advice me ..

Thanks ,
Rajesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on Android version. AFAIK, it was changed on 3.x version (at least I wasn't able to use /system/bin/cat /dev/graphics/fb0 on Xoom devices). You might need to check if the method is available and if not, go with another one.

I would suggest to checkout [this project by oNaiPs](https://github.com/oNaiPs/droid-VNC-server/tree/master/jni/vnc/screenMethods) which has number of different methods for screen capture used.

Comment: hi have a look at this project.. this works some unrooted device also.. how thats possible ... https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.geeksoft.screenshot&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5nZWVrc29mdC5zY3JlZW5zaG90Il0.

Comment: hmm, probably some OEMs haven't properly hide were APIs.

Comment: hi Sorry i am not able to get you ..!

Comment: I mean, that some device manufacturers could left some flaws in their code, so it might be possible to get screenshots using e.g. java reflection without root.

Comment: k thanks for your info., i have reviewed the project which you have referred . it has /dev/graphics/fb0 this command only . i am not able to see any other commands ..

Comment: https://github.com/oNaiPs/droid-VNC-server/blob/master/jni/vnc/screenMethods/adb.c - This method is a stub to grab the screen from the ADB daemon; here's https://github.com/oNaiPs/droid-VNC-server/tree/master/nativeMethods/gralloc special statement for Your question: 'This method should work for tegra2 devices which not use the linux framebuffer', and here: https://github.com/oNaiPs/droid-VNC-server/tree/master/nativeMethods/flinger 'The surfaceflinger method is present from version 2.3.X and should be supported by all devices.' (it uses not fb, but ScreenshotClient for sure)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable replies @sandrstar